# Vue.js Dynamic use string

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to use `vue-native-websocket` and the `wss` is dynamic because it needs an access token.

So I have this:

```
import VueNativeSock from 'vue-native-websocket';
Vue.use(VueNativeSock, this.monitor);

export default {
  created() {
    this.$options.sockets.onmessage = this.handleToggle;
  },
  data() {
    return {
      type: false
    };
  },
 methods: {
    handleToggle(data) {
      const object = JSON.parse(data.data);
      console.log(object);
      this.status = object.data;
    }
  },
  props: ['items', 'monitor']
};
```

As you can see, the `prop` `monitor` is passed but when it comes time to do `Vue.use()`... I get `undefined`. How do I pass a dynamic variable to a `Vue use`?

Comment: This plugin doesn't handle dynamic websocket urls. There are a few issues about it open on github. If that is a requirement for you, suggest you find another library or roll your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Vue.use` is for registering plugins globally.

I didn't use `vue-native-websocket` before. But

```
import VueNativeSock from 'vue-native-websocket';
Vue.use(VueNativeSock, ....);
```

should be done in the place where Vue is initiated (where `new Vue({...})` is, it's in main.js in a typical vue-cli generated project.) . Not inside component.

`Vue.use` should also be executed before `new Vue({...})` in main.js.

Therefore, **I don't think you would be able to make `wss` dynamic, unless this plugin has a specified method for you do to that.**